# Problems with PHP/CSS style dealing with faux columns

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Here's the important chunk of my code:

```
            <div class="cont_table clearfix">
            <div class="main");
                <?php
                                            $number=$_POST['memform']
                    echo("<br>");
                    echo("<br>");
                    echo("<br>");
                    echo("The Post is " . $number . ".");

                    if ($number<1) {
                            echo("<span style=\"color:white\">");
                                echo("Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.");

                                echo("I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it");

                                echo("Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.");

                                echo("I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it");

                                echo("Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.");

                                echo("I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it");  

                            echo("</span>");
                        }        
                        else {
                            ini_set('display_errors',1); 
                            error_reporting(E_ALL);
                            $main_query = $main_query . "A.MEMBER_ID = \"". $number . "\"";
                            $con=mysql_connect("my02.winhost.com","fkinkade","19F1reB1rd99");
                            mysql_select_db("mysql_75053_fgk2",$con);
                            $result1 = mysql_query($main_query,$con); 
                            // for each member name, create the HTML<option> tag with the data name 
                                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                                  {
                                        echo("<br>");
                                        echo($row1['MEMBER_NAME']);
                                  } 
                        }  
                ?>
            </div> 
            <div class="sidebar">
                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

                Nunc ac viverra magna. Pellentesque vitae hendrerit metus. Suspendisse potenti. Integer vitae mauris sit amet libero adipiscing molestie. Phasellus pellentesque magna non lorem commodo feugiat. Sed id lorem nec sapien cursus vehicula. Sed iaculis, urna et cursus facilisis, odio ipsum dignissim felis, vel placerat metus mauris vestibulum lectus. Integer porta consequat mauris, eleifend blandit lorem fringilla quis. Phasellus fermentum velit molestie, porta ante eu, euismod metus.

                I searched StackOverflow to see if there were any fixes to the clicking and dragging issue. I found a JavaScript solution that seemed to work, but it

            </div> 
        </div>
```

The "memform" comes from a form/select that contains a MySQL database driven dropdown list.  I've come across a problem, anytime the browser is refreshed, the previous results of the dropdown list are still displayed.  I want to clear that "MAIN" faux column out, but if I do so, it allows the "SIDEBAR" faux column to take over the enter width of the container.  So, I figured I'd simply try to evaluate the $_POST, see if it has a number, and if not, put in some bogus text (to keep the MAIN column inflated) and color it white.

This works.

However, when I then go back and make another selection from the SELECT element, nothing changes.  It's as if it refuses to go back through the PHP code again.  Yet, without this, and dealing with the previous results being there until you make a new selection, it generates new results every time you make a selection.

How can I make it look "clean" in between browser refreshes and clear the MAIN column of the last selected data from the previous session?

Thanks,

Flynn

Comment: I dont see an AJAX request anywhere. If there isn't one then _no_, of course it wont "go back through the PHP again". PHP is a server-side language - that is to say, you can consider it like an automated typewriter that creates HTML content. It is only executed after the page is requested and before the page is served. It does _not_ execute in the browser. If you want new content generated by the PHP, you have to request the page again with new variables that control its content.

Comment: Ok, I am not familiar at all with AJAX, can you give me a snippet of code and an idea on how to fire it off ?

Comment: Sure. You should take a look at something like: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp for a basic run-down on the process. You can see an example of an auto-suggest feature being implemented here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest - with small differences - (a) they use the `GET` method rather than the `POST` one and (b) the server-side page is ASP rather than PHP - the concept still holds true though. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, enhzflep, but I kinda need something that kicks off "onload", either from document.onload or window.onload, I can't figure that part out.

Comment: No worries. Well, in that case - instead of inline js handling the `onkeyup` event of the text input, you could _either_ (a) use inline js that responded to the `onload` event of the `body` tag, **or** (b) use a couple of js statements in the script section. Namely: `window.addEventListener('load', nameOfFuncToCallWhenPageLoaded, false);` followed by the function that actually gets called. `function nameOfFuncToCallWhenPageLoaded(){ /* do stuff here. */ }`. You can see an example of (b) in action in lines 43 and 45 of the JS in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enhzflep/mnugp/